# Find port number where HDFS is listening

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, mapr

I want to access hdfs with fully qualified names such as :

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://machine-name:8020/user
```

I could also simply access hdfs with

```
hadoop fs -ls /user
```

However, I am writing test cases that should work on different distributions(HDP, Cloudera, MapR...etc) which involves accessing hdfs files with qualified names.

I understand that `hdfs://machine-name:8020` is defined in core-site.xml as `fs.default.name`. But this seems to be different on different distributions. For example, hdfs is maprfs on MapR. IBM BigInsights don't even have `core-site.xml` in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf`.

There doesn't seem to a way hadoop tells me what's defined in `fs.default.name` with it's command line options.

How can I get the value defined in `fs.default.name` reliably from command line?

The test will always be running on namenode, so machine name is easy. But getting the port number(8020) is a bit difficult. I tried lsof, netstat.. but still couldn't find a reliable way.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Below command available in Apache hadoop 2.7.0 onwards, this can be used for getting the values for the hadoop configuration properties. fs.default.name is deprecated in hadoop 2.0, fs.defaultFS is the updated value. Not sure whether this will work incase of maprfs.

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS  # ( new property )
```

or

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.default.name    # ( old property )
```

Not sure whether there is any command line utilities available for retrieving configuration properties values in Mapr or hadoop 0.20 hadoop versions. In case of this situation you better try the same in Java for retrieving the value corresponding to a configuration property.

```
Configuration hadoop conf = Configuration.getConf();
System.out.println(conf.get("fs.default.name"));
```

Comment: The command line utility "hdfs" is not available in earlier hadoop version?

Comment: hdfs command introduced to hadoop from 2.X, this command is not there in 1.X, You may try the second option in that case

Comment: Use 

hadoop conf  -key fs.default.name

for pre 2.x versions.

Comment: @eiram_mahera .. hdfs getconf subcommand was added only in Hadoop-2.7.0, this subcommand is not available in the older hadoop version, Which hadoop version are you using ?

Comment: @sachin, Oh! I am using hadoop 2.6.5. Is there a way to find out name node and portnumber in this version?

Comment: Updated hadoop version in the answer, You need to use the Java API in that case.

Answer (score 12):

fs.default.name is deprecated.

use : `hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS`

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this answer when I was looking for HDFS URI. Generally that's a URL pointing to the namenode. While `hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS` gets me the name of the nameservice but it won't help me building the HDFS URI.

I tried the command below to get a list of the namenodes instead

```
 hdfs getconf -namenodes
```

This gave me a list of all the namenodes, primary first followed by secondary. After that constructing the HDFS URI was simple

```
hdfs://<primarynamenode>/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.default.name
```

Comment: 22/06/23 12:24:57 INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS

Answer (score -1):

Yes,  hdfs getconf -namenodes will show list of namenodes.