# What is the difference b/w setInputPaths(..) and addInputPaths(..)?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop

I was trying to implement simple word count as given in docs from eclipse.
Same Program works on terminal but when I tried to run it in eclipse I pass it arguments from run config

arguments was:

```
/home/rachit/wordcount/input /home/rachit/wordcount/output
```

Got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getBlockIndex(FileInputFormat.java:442)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1315)
```

Then I changed this

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

to

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/home/rachit/wordcount/input"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/home/rachit/wordcount/output"));
```

Point to be Noted : dfs port number was 9000 and it was connected, I can browse the file structure from map_reduce perspective in eclipse I upload the file from there.

`setInputPaths(..)` documentation:

> Sets the given comma separated paths as the list of inputs for the map-reduce job.

`addInputPaths(..)` documentation:

> Add the given comma separated paths to the list of inputs for the map-reduce job.

What is the difference b/w `setInputPaths(..)` and `addInputPaths(..)`?
Why does that make a difference ?

Comment: There is something unclear in your question: is there a connection between the error you described (null pointer exception) and your question about the difference between `setInputPaths` and `addInputPaths`?

Comment: When i replace addInputPaths(..) to setInputPaths(..) it works so why it is happening but when i use addInputPaths it gives me this exception

Comment: But you changed two things at once - you also changed the value from `args[0]` to a literal string.

Comment: yes but the path is same i.e. /home/rachit/wordcount/input

Comment: Print `args[0]`. If it's `/home/rachit/...` then it's *not* the same as `hdfs://localhost:9000/home/rachit/...`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes args[0] it prints /home/rachit..  so i guess it is because of not getting path but still not getting diff b/w setinputpaths and addinputpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A job can have more than one input path. Suppose you have five paths you want in your job. You can do things like:

- Add them one by one in five operations
- Set all five of them together at the same time
- Add two of them, and then add another three.

So, `addInputPath` allows you to add a single path to the existing list of paths.

`addInputPaths` allows you to add several paths to the existing list. If the job had two paths, and you use `addInputPaths` to add three more, you'll have five paths in the job.

`setInputPaths` allows you to set several paths *replacing* the existing list. So if you had two paths, and you use `setInputPaths` to set three paths, you'll have *three* paths at the end.

The difference is betwen *adding* (to the existing list of paths), and *replacing* it.

The error that you got is probably due to not having the correct path in `args[0]` or to having an existing bad path in the job before the part of the code that you have shown. If you are starting with a job that has an empty list of paths, there shouldn't really be a difference between using `add` and using `set`.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to the answer by @RealSkeptic

When you say

> hdfs://localhost:9000/home/rachit/wordcount/input

it goes to the `HDFS file system`.

When you don't prepend `hdfs://localhost:9000/` to the path, it tries to get the files from `local` file system and `not HDFS`, as in your case the local file system is `default file system`.

To change the default file system from local to HDFS, change the `core-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
</property>
```

Once this is done, then you do not need to specify `hdfs://localhost:9000/` both in `addInputPath` and `setInputPaths`, as it will try to get the file from `HDFS file system`.

As the path you have provided existed on HDFS and not on local, it was throwing NullPointerException.

Please also check this documentation: https://github.com/hanborq/hadoop/blob/master/example-confs/conf.secure/core-site.xml

`fs.default.name` is deprecated. Use `fs.defaultFS` instead ([Find port number where HDFS is listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216876/find-port-number-where-hdfs-is-listening/36245602#36245602)).